# Disable click and gray out Listview Items [Android]

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Some items in my `listview` need to be disabled in specific situations. Disabled means that they are grayed out, and not clickable any more. Positions that need to be disabled are stored in `ArrayList` named `positions_to_disable`.

I have successfully done one part of this task: I have disabled clicking on these items by overriding adapter's method `boolean isEnabled(int position);`

```
 @Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {

        for (int j = 0; j < FromWhereActivity.positions_to_disable.size(); j++) {
            if (position == FromWhereActivity.positions_to_disable.get(j)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    return super.isEnabled(position);
}
```

However, I haven't found a way to grey them out. If I try to do the same thing with overriding adapter's method `View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)`, I get more items grayed out when scrolling, probably because this method counts only visible items instead of counting all items in my adapter. 
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Try to get firstVisibleItem from `listView` and the lastVisibleItem ... then grey them out from first to last, I think that should work...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the background of the list item to a StateListDrawable that has a different color for disabled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_disabled"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_normal"/>

</selector>
```

See [State List | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)